# how to cast images using react-native-google-cast npm in react-native application

Tags: react-native, google-cast

how to cast images using  react-native-google-cast npm in react-native application,or is there any npm who can cast image file in react-native,google-cast library takes different parameter,Image URL also but it does not cast image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use contentType:"image/jpg" in castMedia options
& also provide image url in mediaUrl.